# Is it possible to prove that a document was shared at a given time?

Tags: google-drive

If I look at my Google drive, I can see all the documents I have access to in the "Activity" section.

If someone shares a document with me I can see when someone last made changes to the doc.

However if someone decides to unshare it with me, all traces of that doc and that I had access disappear.

Is there someway I can see what documents have been shared with me and then the sharing was revoked?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you can copy any of those documents from the Google Drive folder in your OS to some other non-Google Drive folder. Then by comparing the two folders you can see what no longer exists in your current Google Drive folder.

Comment: This is limited to being prepared. In other words you don't believe that in hindsight this kind of behavior can be proved.

Comment: I don't see how, no. If it's not listed on the [Activity tab](https://drive.google.com/?tab=Xo&authuser=0#activity) where else would one get this information?